# Middleware in Next.js@13+ with Turbopack

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, turbopack

I created a new `Next.js@13.0.5` project with `Turbopack` and added `middleware.ts` file to the project's root directory. When I sent a request(e.g. `/api/search?query=Hello`), the middleware wasn't executed. Where is the location of `middleware.ts` file in the latest `Next.js`?

My middleware looks like:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { query } from 'express-validator';
import validateRequest from '@/lib/request-validation';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log('middleware', request.nextUrl.pathname);

  if (
    request.method === 'GET' &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/search')
  ) {
    const res = validateRequest([
      query('query').isString(),
      query('page').isNumeric(),
      query('perPage').isNumeric(),
    ]);

    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey did you find any resolution. We're using yarn for monorepo and middlware is working only for one project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I recommend to do this in your package.json and don't use turbopack actually since middleware doesn't work with turbopack

```
"dev": "next dev",
"turbo": "next dev --turbo",
```

source:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42921